# Deny directory browsing in a Proftpd / Ubuntu Installation

Tags: ubuntu, security, ftp, proftpd

I used [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588) to set up a [Proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/) installation an Ubuntu 8.04 server... Works well, but the generic user ( userftp ) can run

```
ls
```

and is able to change to any Directory and browse freely on the server ..from the root

```
/
```

and upwards..
I added this line to etc/shells

```
/bin/false
```

in hopes that that would prevent this ...
I really only want the userftp account to be able to upload to the generic

```
/home/FTP-Shared
```

directory, and be able to do nothing else on the server.
How is this accomplished ... This is a headless Ubuntu box..and I am using CLI only .. no GUI admin tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered chrooting proftpd into /home/FTP-Shared?  Then it can't access anything outside of there.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful start...posting full solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Cry Havok is correct, you will have to set up chrooting. 
Also, the /bin/false will restrict the user from ssh'ing to the box. It has nothing to do with the ftp behaviour itself.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, all I had to do was uncomment this line :

```
DefaultRoot                     ~
```

from this file:

```
/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
```

and then run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```